# Adding image trough Web Service API (xmlrpclib) Error. Odoo 10

Tags: python, encoding, base64, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to add an image that I get from another service to my odoo module trough the Web Service API (xmlrpclib). I'm having an error possibly with the encoding.

**Error when I open the product in the browser:**

[image]

**Image that I try to add (I'm downloading the exact content of that image trough the 2ba API):**

https://api.2ba.nl/1/json/Thumbnail/TradeItem?gln=8711389000001&tradeItemId=9834942

**Encoding:**

```
return base64.b64encode(api_call_response.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

I added the encode('utf-8') at the end because otherwise I get an error like: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position. This way I get the same output as https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

**Adding the image:**

Nothing fancy. I just added the field to my already working variable:

```
import functools
import xmlrpclib
......
product['image']        = get_image(api_url, query)
create_record('sync2ba.products', product)
```

**Module:**

```
_name = 'sync2ba.products'
_rec_name = 'ProductId'

image                           = fields.Binary()
```

**View:**

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="products_form_view">
        <field name="name">products.form</field>
        <field name="model">sync2ba.products</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Products Form">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="image" widget="image" class="oe_avatar"/>
......
```